# How can I create a Custom Renderer for a ContentView in Xamarin.Forms MacOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

We're using `Xamarin.Forms` with `MacOS`, and have a custom view `MyCustomView : Xamarin.Forms.ContentView`, and I'm trying to create a custom view renderer for our view, but it's interfering with the rendered view.

Does anyone know how to create a view renderer in my platform project?

This is the code I've tried so far, looking at similar places:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomView), typeof(MyCustomViewRenderer))]
namespace Mac.Renderers
{
    public class MyCustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.ContentView, AppKit.NSView>
    {
        public MyCustomViewRenderer()
        {
           // My implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Event when the implementation is left blank, having this custom renderer is affecting the display of the ContentView, so I think this code must not be right - is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "is affecting the display of the ContentView, so I think this code must not be right" ? In what way is it being affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix your issue by changing your class to inherit from `VisualElementRenderer<T>` instead.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomView), typeof(MyCustomViewRenderer))]
namespace Mac.Renderers
{
    public class MyCustomViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<ContentView>
    {
        public MyCustomViewRenderer()
        {
           // My implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Page has a default Renderer "PageRenderer", do not understand why ContentView does not. It would be nice if there was a ContentViewRenderer.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. The issue we were having was the borders not being correctly rendered when using the other custom renderer. We had a few views nested, so I couldn't identify exactly where the problem came from, just that removing the old `ExportRenderer` fixed it. The `VisualElementRenderer` here works just fine though